# Filtering Noteboard comments on a custom page based on query string parameter

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm using a custom webpart to display a list item. The item id is passed to this webpart through a query string. I have added this webpart and a noteboard webpart on a page. I would like to capture the noteboard comments entered against the list item being viewed. Is it possible to display the noteboard comments based on the itemid passed in the query string?

Currently I can see comments entered for other list items too and not filtered based on query string.

Thanks

Comment: The noteboard webpart stores the comment based on the page url. It does consider the query string parameters. So my comments about query string parameters not being considered is not correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it supports filtering, but you could do this with JavaScript if you try to disable paging and hide/show elements based on query string, like this (using hash for simplicity):

```
$('.ms-socialCommentItem').hide();
$('.ms-socialCommentItem:has(.socialcomment-contents:contains("' + 
    window.location.hash.slice(1) + '"))').show();
```

Comment: Here is an example using input element: https://gist.github.com/3792439